# "escopo" e "escopo-de-variáveis" são tags que cobrem o mesmo escopo?

Tags: debate, tags

Me pareceu que no fundo elas são sinônimas. Alguém discorda? Ou podemos fundí-las? Alguma ressalva ou recomendação?

Comment: Eu deixaria só "escopo" pra um caso como `static function Escopo()`  não dar margem para discussão

Comment: Parece que a primeira engloba a segunda tranquilamente.

Comment: Eu acho que não. "Escopo" pode ser escopo de algum assunto, enquanto que "escopo de variáveis" é algo mais específico, como uma variável de uma linguagem. Mas aí vem a questão: que escopo de algum assunto? Pode ter, tipo: "isso é do escopo de Java? PHP?"... só pra dar uma ideia. Acho que as duas tags podem abranger assuntos diferentes.

Comment: @Sam mas por que haveria uma discussão sobre "escopo de assuntos" no site? Isso parece ser assunto do meta. Mesmo assim, a definição e uso de escopo nos dois casos é o mesmo.

Comment: @Sam por mais que faça sentido "escopo de um assunto", não seria usado como tag, certo? Seria somente uma palavra solta no texto. Lembre-se que a tag é para indexar somente as parts do conteúdo relacionadas ao ..escopo... do site.  :D

Comment: Podem fundir. Quando são levantadas questões de escopo na página normalmente são relacionadas a escopo de variáveis. Qualquer outra significação poderá ser deduzida da própria pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/escopo

Comment: Eu não consigo compreender o que é escopo de variáveis.

Comment: @JorgeB. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101

Comment: Relacionada: [Como se traduz “scope” se tratando de desenvolvimento de software?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6330/153)

Answer (score 11):

Não acho que elas são inteiramente sinônimas. Na grande maioria a tag `escopo` é utilizada para referenciar o escopo de variáveis, mas poderia também ser escopo de funções ou classes.

O escopo, na verdade, é o mesmo sempre, apenas quando utilizado `escopo-de-variáveis` está deixando um pouco mais explícito que será analisado apenas as variáveis dentro do escopo e não ele como um todo.

Porém, analisando as perguntas, não consegui ver alguma que justificasse a existência dessa tag "tão" específica e substituí-la por `escopo` não prejudicaria de forma alguma a pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim sendo, eu voto na fusão das duas mantendo a `escopo`.